# Wrong files displayed in SSH, is there something to flush a SSH Terminal Session?

Tags: caching, ssh, connection, terminal

I have a problem which I will try to reproduce:

1)I get a SSH connection using the Terminal to access a remote server.

2)Then I run the command `ls` to list all content.

3)Here´s the problem: I don't see the real content (folder and files), I just see other files which don't exist at all.

I contacted my hosting support and they told me that they run the same command `ls` and they could see the real content. Then they told me that it could be a cache problem of my terminal and then I should clear my sessions.

**How can I do this?**

If I disconnect and reconnect the problem still persist.

The folder is: www

the content I get is:

```
www/ $ ls
bin    certs    conf  error   htdocs.off  include  logs    modules  sbin
build  cgi-bin  doc   htdocs  icons       lib      manual  private
```

What I expected is:

```
authorize.php        index.html      MAINTAINERS.txt  sites
cgi-bin          index.php       misc         
CHANGELOG.txt        INSTALL.mysql.txt   modules          themes
COPYRIGHT.txt        INSTALL.pgsql.txt   phpinfo.php      update.php
cron.php         install.php         profiles         UPGRADE.txt
drupal-noviembre.esproj  INSTALL.sqlite.txt  README.txt       web.config
drush            INSTALL.txt         robots.txt       xmlrpc.php
includes         LICENSE.txt         scripts
```

Comment: are you really in the right folder? try the comand `pwd` to list your path.

Comment: checked: yes I am in the www folder of my hosting.

Comment: try `cd htdocs` and then do a `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in your `www` directory of your webhoster and are looking for your `htdocs` folder where your webserver document root is.

Go in the `htdocs` folder:

```
$ cd htdocs
```

Comment: btw: I'd like to know why someone down-voted my question. Why is this action allowed? This is correct quetions, isn't it?

Comment: You can't see why somebody did that. It's a bit of a newbie question and just wrong. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: I see but I still think that the downvote is really unfair...

Comment: The down vote likely means the question isn’t going to be of general value to others, because it’s about a very specific user scenario that others are unlikely to encounter. That’s why I’m down voting it, anyway. That’s also why I’m flagging this as “too localized”.